# iOS: Simple question about the app design and how to share a NSDictionary among viewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a simple design question. This code is in my appDelegate. I use it to load all images in a NSDictionary categories. Successively I pass the dictionary to the init method of the main NavigationViewController. Successively I pass the dictionary through all viewControllers pushed by the NavigationViewController, because I'm using the same icons everywhere.

I was wondering if this is the correct approach, or am I just wasting memory. In other terms, should I pass the dictionary through viewControllers, or should I use a singleton.. or what ? The reason I'm currently adopting this approach is that I don't have any reference from viewControllers to the app delegate.

```
//load categories pictures
NSArray *categoriesKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                           @"comedy",
                           @"commercial",
                           @"education",
                           @"family",
                           @"media",
                           @"music", 
                           @"performing",
                           @"sport",
                           nil];

categories = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *categKey in categoriesKeys) {
    UIImage * categImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[[@"icons/" stringByAppendingString:categKey] stringByAppendingString:@".png"]];
    [categories setObject:categImage forKey:categKey];
}
```

**Update**:

viewController init method

```
FlickrAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

categories = appDelegate.categories;
categKeys = appDelegate.categoriesKeys;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put all the code in your appDelegate in a function and call that function in applicationDidFinishLaunching method . Access  dictionary anywhere in the application like this

```
appNameDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

[appdelegate.categories objectForKey:@"WhatEver"];
```

Comment: All right, so this means that the UIViewController are supposed to know the interface of the appDelegate, correct ? But if this is this not bad OO design, than I will go for it.

Comment: @Patrick It's a requirement for a global var. Look appDelegate is an singleton class so that's why any instance vars with properties can be accessible anywhere in the app.

Comment: OK. One last question: what about the code I've added to the question ? I'm assigning the objects to the class members (I guess they are called iVar). Is it wrong ? am I allocating the dictionaries twice ?

Comment: No, But you need to read some memory management guides also objective-c 2.0 properties. There are many articles on internet. You just need to read them carefully. Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a Singleton. A lot of people like placing shared code in the AppDelegate, but then that file gets cluttered and it becomes unclear what is going on throughout the file. Having a Singleton dedicated to this logic separates the code and makes it easier to change.